# How to pass Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate as a parameter to a method?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, delegates

I have a higher order function for handling transaction:

```
public static void ExecuteTransaction<Context, FunctionParameter>(Action<FunctionParameter> functionToBeExecuted,
                                                                           FunctionParameter parameter,
                                                                           Context context)
                                                                           where Context : DbContext
        {
            using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    functionToBeExecuted(parameter);
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

How can i change the ExecuteTransaction method to accept this method and its parameter?:

```
public void DeleteBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    var results = DbSet.Where(predicate).ToList();
    DbSet.RemoveRange(results);
}
```

Comment: `Action<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to pass `DeleteBy` to `ExecuteTransaction`, and let `ExecuteTransaction` run the method.

Assuming you have a `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` to act as the parameter of `DeleteBy` prepared already:

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> param = entity => /*some lambda that returns a bool */;
```

you can pass `DeleteBy` directly, without any changes to `ExecuteTransaction`, because `DeleteBy` matches the signature of `Action<T>`:

```
ExecuteTransaction(DeleteBy, param, context);
```

The compiler will automatically infer that `FunctionParameter` is `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`.

Comment: Thx thats it i am a newb with c#.